# How do I generate ngrams in a dataframe so that each ngram creates a new row?

Tags: r, multiple-columns, sapply

I am trying to use ngram_asweka to identify the ngrams in a character vector, line by line, while maintaining data like item number, participant/control, etc. I have tried tapply and sapply without success. My dataframe has more columns, but the basic format looks like this:

| Item | Phrase |
| --- | --- |
| 1. | Cats and dogs |
| 2. | birds and bees |

I need it to output

| Item | Phrase | Ngram |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Cats and dogs | cats and dogs |
| 1. | Cats and dogs | cats and |
| 1. | Cats and dogs | and dogs |
| 2. | birds and bees | birds and bees |
| 2. | birds and bees | birds and |

This is my ngram function

```
myngram <-function(x) {
  x<- ngram_asweka(x, min = 2, max = 5, sep = " ") %>% data.frame()
  return(x)
```

And here is the code I have tried that isn't working.

```
x<-tapply(df$phrase, df$ID, myngram) %>% data.frame()
```

The error code says "Error in ngram_asweka (x, min = 2, max = 5, sep = " ") : attempt to set index 2/2 in SET_STRING_ELT

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your example for testing, you may want `max = 3` for `ngram_asweka` given that the length of the strings there is only 3 words (3-grams).

Here is one option using `tidyverse`. You can use `group_by` to get results for each `item`, and `group_modify` to create rows of results, including the phrase and n-grams.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ngram)

df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  group_modify(function(x, y) 
     tibble(phrase = x$phrase,
            ngram = ngram_asweka(x$phrase, min = 2, max = 3, sep = " ")))
```

If you have other columns you want to include in output with a larger data set, you can do the following alternative:

```
df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  group_modify(~ bind_cols(select(.x, everything()),
                           ngram = ngram_asweka(.x$phrase, min = 2, max = 3, sep = " ")))
```

**Output**

```
   item phrase         ngram         
  <dbl> <chr>          <chr>         
1     1 Cats and dogs  Cats and dogs 
2     1 Cats and dogs  Cats and      
3     1 Cats and dogs  and dogs      
4     2 birds and bees birds and bees
5     2 birds and bees birds and     
6     2 birds and bees and bees
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(item = c(1, 2), phrase = c("Cats and dogs", "birds and bees"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```